# What are the possible test scenario's to test a Text field?

Tags: manual-testing, testcase

Consider the text field accepts alpha-numeric characters. What could be some unique and out of the box test scenario's/cases that could be useful in finding an important defect.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what the text field is supposed to accept and what it's for.

If it's meant to accept specific formats of data, your tests will be different than if it's meant to accept free-form data. For example,  text fields are often used for postal code entry. For that, there's likely to be validation that the postal code format matches the official format for the country (USA: xxxxx or xxxxx-xxxx where x is any number, Australia: xxxx where x is any number - those are the only two I know offhand).

Some other considerations:

- Is there a way to get invalid input into the field? Most browsers will allow drag and drop or copy/paste into fields: this is a common way to put invalid data into a field. The key thing is to handle the invalid input gracefully.
- Is there a way to override the field length limitations? Copy/paste and drag and drop can do this. I've also seen holding down a key do it, particularly if a control key is involved.
- Are there limits on the characters the field should accept? If you're limiting to English alphanumeric, the field needs to handle other characters gracefully.
- Special character handling - does the field handle characters that have specific meanings in HTML, JavaScript, the back-end programming language used, SQL? Does it handle leading spaces? *Should* it handle leading spaces?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have some requirements at first about text field? There are some basic checks:

- Check possibility to input minimum number of symbols
- Check possibility to input maximum number of symbols
- Can you input uppercase and lowercase together?
- Can you input special symbols?
- Can you copy and paste inside text field?
- Check different unicode symbols
- Check cyrillc
- Check arabian

Etc. I hope this tips could help you.

Answer (score 1):

- Max/Min-length (Display and correct after save/reload)
- UTF-8 display support (I use [the UTF-8 Sampler data](http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/utf8/))
- Server-side validation of UTF-8 length (Multibyte chars are sometimes counted as two chars)
- Clear (Backspace, delete)
- Cut and paste

To visually verify the length fast I created a [file](http://www.vanreijmersdal.nl/609/verify-the-maxlenght-of-input-fields-visually/) which looks like this:

```
0--------10--------20--------30--------40--------50--------60--------70--------80--------90--------'
100------`---------`---------`---------`---------`---------`---------`---------`---------`---------'
```

Comment: Error 404 - Not Found. Apologies, but we were unable to find what you were looking for. Perhaps searching will help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on requirement for the text field scenarios will differ.
Suppose when we try to prepare scenario for name fields.
1.Check with Equivalence (i.e.) 
Maximum length of field,
Minimum length of field,
Exact field length,
Numerical,
Alpha numerical,
Special characters,
Empty field,
Enter input into text box,
Copy and paste,
Try with browser cache .

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

            StackExchange.ready(function () {

                StackExchange.using("postValidation", function () {
                    StackExchange.postValidation.initOnBlurAndSubmit($('#post-form'), 2, 'answer');
                });

!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
<head>

<title>
```

manual testing - What are the possible test scenario's to test a Text field? - Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange

```
            StackExchange.question.init({showAnswerHelp:true,totalCommentCount:0,shownCommentCount:0,highlightColor:'#F4A83D',backgroundColor:'#FFF',questionId:8067});

            styleCode();

                StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToQuestion('244', '8067');
                                                                StackExchange.using("gps", function () { StackExchange.gps.trackOutboundClicks('#content', '.post-text'); });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: !DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
<head>

<title>manual testing - What are the possible test scenario&#39;s to test a Text field? - Software Quality Assurance &amp; Testing Stack Exchange</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/sqa/img/favicon.ico?v=79bc26a25b7f">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/sqa/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=0558b5cf36fe">
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Software Quality Assurance &amp; Testing Stack Exchange" href="/

Comment: I want to know HTML contentents can be added in the message box or no?